# How i can customize theme in Pimcore CMS

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system, themes, pimcore

I am using Pimcore CMS and i want to change default theme to my template, and i need any source to learn more about it,and if there any tutorial discus this CMS

Mohammed

Comment: It would be a great help if there would be a tutorial available on 'how to theme Pimcore'.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to modify the template lies within the /website folder.

Most important subfolders are:

- controllers - these are the controllers (C in MVC)
- views - views and layouts (V in MVC)
- static - static files like CSS, JavaScript and image files

Models in Pimcore world are Objects (not PHP objects but Pimcore Object Classes). 
Pimcore autogenerates PHP Classes that are then saved in /website/var/classes folder - based on your configuration in Settings > Objects > Classes. Do not change those files directly as they will get overwritten as soon as you save your Object Class. If you want to extend your object classes you need to use classmapping:
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/Class-Mappings+-+Overwrite+pimcore+models

You can read more about objects here:
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/Data+Objects

Keep in mind that Pimcore is not a system like Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla, so changing a template takes a bit more development knowledge and understanding of the system.

Comment: thanks Igor Benko ,but what about the modle? where does it exist?

Comment: @MohammedNazli I updated my answer describing the models in Pimcore

Comment: Update: As of Pimcore 5 views are now located in `app/Resources/views`